# Can I trigger travis ci to build my app by creating git tag?

Tags: github, continuous-integration, travis-ci

I want to trigger Travis CI to build and deploy when I create tag via github web interface. I can't find information about triggers for Travis CI. So can I do it?

Comment: https://engineering.hexacta.com/triggering-deploys-with-git-tags-21993147352f

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A build should automatically start when a new tag is created. To deploy you have to add the follow bit to the `deploy` section:

```yaml
on:
   tags: true
```

Here is a complete example:

```yaml
language: php

php:
- 5.3
- 5.4

deploy:
  provider: heroku
  strategy: git
  skip_cleanup: true
  app: myapp
  on:
    tags: true
    php: '5.4'
  api_key:
    secure: NL10DAVFJJPk7mHdKeN3q5hpKgRq/gKpEnsXeBb7dDcnW0XuwmO88srMVbYHOA6w3kw50aPkKZ1AirElPjcpm2uxEz/tW7PpshY8fGDKdCyuczXKh24avTpD8nF8lskTIPXVpwWBYxCoFziRsd+eQBKHCsRyrQcv0mjg2j2MoNE=
```

Travis CI has a nice [documentation about all the possibilities](http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/deployment/#Conditional-Releases-with-on%3A).

Comment: Also, can I trigger travis builds only on tags and ignore commits?

Comment: I don't think that's possible. You could write a build script that checks if the current commit is a tagged commit and immediatly stop if it isn't. Travis [provides a lot environment variables](http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/ci-environment/#Environment-variables), the one you would need is `TRAVIS_TAG`.

Comment: This is not exactly what he wants.  It is just trigging "deployment" part,  not trigging the build.